# ERROR: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql

**¿Por qué me da este error y no puedo eliminar al usuario?**

**clientes**:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes (
    email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    apellidos VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    dni VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    telefono VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    direccion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ciudad VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE clientes ADD INDEX(ciudad);
```

**cpostales**:

```
CREATE TABLE cpostales (
    cpostal VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ciudad VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ciudad) REFERENCES clientes(ciudad)
);
```

**Quiero eliminar un cliente de la tabla "clientes".** Ese DNI existe en la tabla.

```
DELETE FROM clientes WHERE clientes.dni = '78945612V'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece que tienes la llave foranea invertida, deberías en todo caso crearla en `clientes` y no en `cpostales`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ¿y en cpostales no? Entonces cómo quedaría... ¿No sé si es más correcta tu forma o la de la respuesta adjuntada?

Comment: A ver, me imagino (por que es lo habitual) que lo que buscas es que no se pueda borrar una ciudad si hay un cliente que la usa (o cualquier otra entidad), para esto la FK va en clientes

Comment: Si es así, además la relación no debiera ser por ciudad sino por codigo postal, ya que una misma ciudad podría tener múltiples códigos postales

Comment: ¿Entonces cómo quedaría la estructura de la creación de tablas? Sé que cualquier ciudad puede tener varios CP pero quería simplificarlo a uno.

Comment: La relación cliente / ciudad debiera ser por el codigo postal, sencillamente por que este es un dato que vas a necesitar a nivel de cliente y este a su vez te relaciona con la ciudad, por lo que eventualmente no necesitarías cargar este dato. La idea podría ser así: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8557e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu tabla `cpostales` tienes una llave foránea vinculandose con la tabla `clientes` así:

```
FOREIGN KEY (ciudad) REFERENCES clientes(ciudad)
```

Pero por defecto no permitirá que el valor vinculado sea eliminado, entonces puedes a esa declaración agregarle esto:

```
FOREIGN KEY (ciudad) REFERENCES clientes(ciudad) ON DELETE CASCADE
```